# Manipulating the cell style of pyplot's imshow with data of another data layer

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I have a 3d data set that is actually two 2D matrices.

Example data:

```
z = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=100, size=(6,5,2))
```

Think of it as a 2d matrix with two layers. Speaking in analogies, one layer (`[:,:,0]`) could be the price of an item from 0$ to 100$ and the other layer (`[:,:,1]`) is an indication on how much I like it (0 - 100). Now I want to plot an `imshow` plot for the second layer. The map would then show me which item are more desirable to buy and which are not.

```
plt.imshow(z[:,:,1])
plt.show()
```

But now let's assume, I only have 80 $ in my pocket. So I need to mask every item that costs more than 80 $. I would like to do that by changing the style of that cell, e.g. placing a red cross over it, or changing the alpha-value or such.

In research of an answer, I stumbled across a technique on how to change the style of the text color inside, which is nice but not exactly what I am looking for:

```
for i, j in itertools.product(range(z.shape[0]), range(z.shape[1])):
    plt.text(j, i, format(z[i, j, 1], '.2f'),
             ha="center", va="center",
             color="black" if z[i, j, 0] < 80 else "red")
```

My result looks like this:
[image: Good idea, but not exactly what I need]

The interpretation would be that I am going to buy the item in row 3, col 4 because I love it and it seems to be under 80 $. I don't care about how much it costs, as long as it's not "marked".

If I only had one layer to plot colors from in my `imshow`, I guess I could solve it by manipulating the colormap and setting each color with a value > 80 $ to red or give it another style. But I don't know how to do it with data from another matrix. Maybe there is a way like with the text labels, with an if-statement to check for styles in `imshow`?

My ideal output would look like this:

[image: Ideal output]

But other ways of marking excluded cells are highly welcome.

Comment: If you make those cells you can't affort buying red you loose the information about how much you like the item. Is that really desired? I think currently it's pretty nice to see at the same time which items you like and which items you can affort via the red text color.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Changing the cell color is not wanted. But changing cell style adds another important piece of information. To be concrete: I am trying to plot RMSE values of my model, but want to "mask" the runs which have an R² below a certain threshold. This is important, because only then my results can be interpreted. Adding the numbers instead will not look any good in my publication (grids are too small, I don't meet minimum font size requirements)

Comment: What would "style" be, if not color?

Comment: Maybe opacity if that looks good. Or added lines with + or - 45 ° orientation, ...

Comment: Ok, sorry, I can't know if opacity allows a meaningful visual in your case (but I would guess it's hard to grasp, unless you mean 100% transparency). I also cannot know what `...` means. I simply cannot guess what this question asks for. If you have a concrete question on how to achieve a certain thing, please clarify.

Comment: I marked as duplicate of a question asking how to add crosses to imshow heatmaps.  (A 45° line is half a cross). If you need something else, ask a new question with more details on the desired outcome.

Comment: The cross idea is actually pretty nice, I will definetely consider this! Please also find an updated image manipulation on how the output could look like with inclined lines.

Comment: I added a duplicate on how to add hatching to imshow plots.

Comment: In the meantime, I adapted the crosses (they work like a charm) and I will do the - hatching, it's called? I'll decide on what looks better in the end. Thank you for helping me out!